# Sending NUnit test case inputs to Hexawise (or similar service) via HTTP POST for pairwise analysis

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

All,

I'm trying to build up our pairwise coverage analysis for current and future tests on our project.  In particular, we want to make sure that our existing NUnit tests are covering the most important pairwise cases.

To that end, I want to create a helper method that will take a list of all the different test cases that we have and forward them to [Hexawise](http://www.hexawise.com/) (UPDATE: I posted on their internal support site, and Hexawise doesn't have an API for this) or some similar pairwise analysis software.  I want to do this directly in the code, probably via a POST command to a rest client.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure why not contact the developers and see if they have exposed an API to allow you to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I posted on their forums shortly before posting here.  Response I got back was that they don't have an API to do this.  So, looks like Hexawise isn't an option.

Comment: The only other way then is to see what the request packet looks like when you use the web interface and see if you can emulate it, not ideal and can be very tricky also fragile if they change the ui/format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pairwiser (developed by Inductive) is a pairwise tool that has an API for doing exactly what you want. It also supports other common tasks related to pairwise testing.